# Proper likelihood function in acceptance probability of Gibbs Sampler

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs, expectation-maximization, metropolis-hastings

I have a question about the acceptance ratio used when implementing a random walk M-H in a gibbs sampler to generate sample paths of an unobservable process. When computing the likelihood of a set of parameters, does the likelihood also include the likelihood of each jump in the latent process given $ \theta $ ?

The following is a simplified motivating example. Data is generated from the following process:

$$ c_{i,t} = \alpha + \beta y_{t} + \epsilon_{i,t} $$
where
$$ dy_{t} = -\kappa y_{t} + N(0,1) $$

Thus, $ Y $, which is unobservable and independent of the constant term, follows a Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process.

I'm trying to estimate $ \theta = (\alpha, \beta, \kappa) $ using the EM algorithm where samples of the OU process are drawn from a gibbs sampler using random walk M-H.

When drawing samples, I start with $ Y^{(0)}_{t} = 0 $ for $ t = 0,1,2...T$. I'm going to draw a new candidate $y_t$ from $ N(Y^{(n-1)}_t, 2) $ with acceptance probability

$$min (\dfrac{L(\theta | C, Y^{(n-1)}_{(-t)},Y_t = y_t)}{L(\theta | C, Y^{(n-1)}_{t})}, 1) $$

My question is: Are the likelihood functions in the acceptance probability a joint probability of observing all values of $ C $ and the probability of going from $ Y_{t-1} -> y_t -> Y_{t+1} $ or just of observing all values of $C$? In other words, does the likelihood function look more like (when restricting the likelihood function to values of $c_{i,t}$ for one time period)

$$ \prod_{j=1}^N \phi(c_{j,t} - \alpha - \beta y_t) $$

or

$$ \lbrace \prod_{j=1}^N \phi(c_{j,t} - \alpha - \beta y_t) \rbrace \cdot p(y_t | Y^{(n-1)}_{t-1}) \cdot p(Y^{(n-1)}_{t+1} | y_t)$$

I have a similar question for the likelihood function I'm trying to maximize in the M-step of the EM algorithm. I assume when finding the $\kappa$ that maximizes the likelihood function across all sample paths, I'm supposed to include the joint likelihood of jumping from $y_{t-1}$ to $y_t$ for each jump in each sample path?

Comment: If your sampler is using RWMH, how is it Gibbs?

Comment: Sorry, I was adopting the notation from a paper who's methodology I'm trying to follow. I assumed it was Gibbs because when generating a sample path of $Y$ I take a new draw for $Y_t$ holding all other periods of the chain constant. Likewise, I thought it was RWMH because of the way I draw new candidates of $Y_t$ from previous chains. If this is the incorrect terminology, I apologize, but I am still trying to figure out how to implement the steps.

Comment: @TylerS Perhaps you could post a link to the paper in question. I for one find it difficult to follow your notation and terminology.

Comment: Sure. The methodology is outlined in Apendices A & B of http://www.stanford.edu/~duffie/fcdt.pdf